# From column of lists to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column formatted like this:

```
American express,Visa,Master Card,Diners
American express,Visa,Master Card,Bancomat
all
Visa,Master Card,Diners,Banco
```

I want to create different columns for each element with 1 or 0 if the given card is found in the list or not.

The expected results should be something like this:

```
Visa    American Express    Master Card   Diners    Bancomat
1       1                   1             1         0
1       1                   1             0         1
1       1                   1             1         1
1       0                   1             1         0
```

Is there a way in pandas to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with processing `all` column by [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
print (df)
                                          col
0    American express,Visa,Master Card,Diners
1  American express,Visa,Master Card,Bancomat
2                                         all
3            Visa,Master Card,Diners,Bancomat

df = df['col'].str.get_dummies(',')

df = df.add(df.pop('all'), axis=0)
#alternative
#df += df.pop('all')[:, None]
print (df)
   American express  Bancomat  Diners  Master Card  Visa
0                 1         0       1            1     1
1                 1         1       0            1     1
2                 1         1       1            1     1
3                 0         1       1            1     1
```